# How to unset foreach loop main array (the one is being iterated) inside the loop itself?

Tags: php, foreach

I have two `foreach` loops like below.

The idea is to process type 2 before type 1 in order. Code below works just fine but I was wondering how can I use `unset` to achieve same result instead of using another array `$processed` to keep track of what was processed.

I know that PHP foreach clones/copies the `$data` array for iteration. In other words, is it possible to `unset` type 2 from `$data` in second `foreach` loop and somehow first `foreach` loop skip them?

I know that PHP foreach clones/copies array for iteration.

```
  $data = array(
    array('type' => 1),
    array('type' => 2),
    array('type' => 2),
    array('type' => 2),
    array('type' => 1),
    array('type' => 2),
    array('type' => 2),
);

$processed = array();
foreach ($data as $firstKey => $firstValue) {

    if (in_array($firstKey, $processed)) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($data as $secondKey => $secondValue) {
        if ($secondValue['type'] == 2) {
            echo $secondValue['type'] . " processed " . "<br/>";
            $processed[] = $secondKey; // can I use unset here?
        }
    }

    echo $firstValue['type'] . " processed" . "<br/>";
}
```

**Update**
Hopefully with this update I can get my intention out.

Each child has a reference to its parent. All children need to be processed before its parent. Code below should work just fine. you can try it and the output of code below is the desired behavior.  I would like to do it with `unset` if possible.

```
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'ref' => null, 'name' => 'parent 1'),
    array('id' => 2, 'ref' => 1, 'name' => 'child 1'),
    array('id' => 3, 'ref' => 1, 'name' => 'child 2'),
    array('id' => 4, 'ref' => 1, 'name' => 'child 3'),
    array('id' => 5, 'ref' => null, 'name' => 'parent 2'),
    array('id' => 6, 'ref' => 5, 'name' => 'child 1'),
    array('id' => 7, 'ref' => 5, 'name' => 'child 2'),
    array('id' => 8, 'ref' => null, 'name' => 'parent 3'),
    array('id' => 9, 'ref' => 8, 'name' => 'child 1'),
    array('id' => 10, 'ref' => 8, 'name' => 'child 2'),
);

$processed = array();
foreach ($data as $ref => $firstValue) {

    if (in_array($ref, $processed)) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($data as $secondKey => $secondValue) {
        if ($secondValue['ref'] == $firstValue['id']) {
            echo $secondValue['id'] . "- " . $secondValue['name'] . " processed " . "<br/>";
            $processed[] = $secondKey;
        }
    }


    echo $firstValue['id'] . "- " . $firstValue['name'] . " processed" . "<br/>";
    echo "<hr/>";
}
```

Code above output:

```
2- child 1 processed 
3- child 2 processed 
4- child 3 processed 
1- parent 1 processed
6- child 1 processed 
7- child 2 processed 
5- parent 2 processed
9- child 1 processed 
10- child 2 processed 
8- parent 3 processed
```

Comment: Do you really want to do the second loop **inside** the first loop, rather than **after** it?

Comment: Yes, you can use `unset($data[$firstKey]);`. Did you try it, and what problem did you have?

Comment: Wait, with your updated question, you want 2s to be processed first before 1, then 4s before 3? What's the logic behind processing order? Do the 4s also come first before the 2s? How about 3s, do they get processed before the 2s?

Comment: I removed my update. it is really hard to come up with pseudo example for a real application here. please ignore the update!

Comment: I get what you wanted to do with the original question, not so much with that earlier edit, but it looked like you wanted to always  processes higher numbered types first. Wouldn't sorting be an option for you then?

Comment: the point here is I'd like to process 2s before 1 in the order they appear. It means that process first group of 2s then first 1 then process second group of 2s and then the second 1. sort will process them independently and not in the order I'd like.

Comment: Then I guess I didn't get what you wanted to do. I tried running your sample code up there and here's what happens: It processes all the type=2s, then does a single type=1, then reruns through all the type=2s again, then does another type=1. That doesn't exactly sound like what you are describing (process first group of 2s, then 1, then next group of 2s, then the second 1).

Comment: please see my update. run the second sample code and you'll see the expected behavior.

Comment: It seems like the best way to do this is with a recursive function. When you're processing a parent, you call the function recursively with the parent ID, and then it processes all its children.

Comment: Ok, so there's a parent-child relationship going on here. Yes, I too think a recursive function would work best

Comment: I updated my answer to match up with your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version that doesn't require unsetting anything. It just tests the type. For each type 1 entry, it processes all the type 2 entries first, then processes that type 1 entry.

```
<?php

$data = array(
              array('type' => 1),
              array('type' => 2),
              array('type' => 2),
              array('type' => 2),
              array('type' => 1),
              array('type' => 2),
              array('type' => 2),
              );

foreach ($data as $firstKey => $firstValue) {
    if ($firstValue['type'] == 1) {
        foreach ($data as $secondKey => $secondValue) {
            if ($secondValue['type'] == 2) {
                echo $secondValue['type'] . " processed " . "<br/>";
            }
        }
        echo $firstValue['type'] . " processed" . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Another way to do this, that doesn't require testing the types in the inner loops, is simply to make two arrays: `$dataType1` contains all the type 1 entries in `$data`, and `$dataType2` contains all the type 2 entries. Then you just use simple nested loops:

```
foreach ($dataType1 as $firstValue) {
    foreach ($dataType2 as $secondValue) {
        echo $secondValue['type'] . " processed " . "<br/>";
    }
    echo $firstValue['type'] . " processed" . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: need to be process in order: all 2s then 1 then 2s then 1. I could achieve the code you wrote by sorting. Your code process all 1s and 2s separate and not in the order I'd like.

Comment: I don't understand. I process all 2s then all 1s. Isn't that what you said? Do you mean that for each 2 you want to then process all 1's?

Comment: Could you update the question to show the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Redoing my answer to match up with the OP's updated question.

Here is one method of achieving similar output using a recursive function

```
function processData(&$data, $ref = null)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if ($ref !== null && $value['ref'] !== $ref) {
            continue;
        }
        $data = processData($data, $value['id']);
        echo $value['id'] . "- " . $value['name'] . " processed" . "<br/>";
        unset($data[$key]);
    }

    return $data;
}

processData($data);
```

This function will modify your array though, constantly unsetting elements as it works through it.